# How to fix "ImportError: No module name apache" error in Jython and HBase

Tags: hadoop, hbase, jython

I am trying to run the following Jython code to scan a hbase table:

```
    import java.lang
    from org.apache.hadoop.hbase import TableName, HBaseConfiguration
    from org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client import Connection, ConnectionFactory,         
    Result, ResultScanner, Table, Admin
    from org.apache.hadoop.conf import Configuration
    conf = HBaseConfiguration.create()
    connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(conf)
    admin = connection.getAdmin()
    tableName = TableName.valueOf('station')
    table = connection.getTable(tableName)
    cf = "stn"
    attr = "name"
    scanner = table.getScanner(cf)
    while 1:
         result = scanner.next()
         if not result:
            break
         print java.lang.String(result.row),   
         java.lang.String(result.getValue(cf, attr))
```

I am using the following command to try to run it:

```
jython test1.py
```

But I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test1.py", line 2, in <module>
    from org.apache.hadoop.hbase import TableName, HBaseConfiguration
ImportError: No module named apache
```

How do I resolve this? I have installed hbase in standalone mode and it is working fine(created a few sample tables using hbase shell).

**UPDATE:**
As suggested in the comments, I tried the following command to run it:

> jython -Dpython.path=./hbase-1.4.8/lib/hbase-common-1.4.8.jar
>   test1.py

I am now getting the following error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "test1.py", line 2, in
>   
>       from org.apache.hadoop.hbase import TableName, HBaseConfiguration java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/io/RawComparator
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.NamespaceDescriptor.(NamespaceDescriptor.java:45)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.TableName.(TableName.java:82)
>           at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
>           at org.python.core.Py.loadAndInitClass(Py.java:991)
>           at org.python.core.Py.findClassInternal(Py.java:926)
>           at org.python.core.Py.findClassEx(Py.java:977)
>           at org.python.core.packagecache.SysPackageManager.findClass(SysPackageManager.java:133)
>           at org.python.core.packagecache.PackageManager.findClass(PackageManager.java:33)
>           at org.python.core.packagecache.SysPackageManager.findClass(SysPackageManager.java:122)
>           at org.python.core.PyJavaPackage.**findattr_ex**(PyJavaPackage.java:134)
>           at org.python.core.PyObject.**findattr**(PyObject.java:946)
>           at org.python.core.imp.importFromAs(imp.java:1160)
>           at org.python.core.imp.importFrom(imp.java:1132)
>           at org.python.pycode._pyx0.f$0(test1.py:13)
>           at org.python.pycode._pyx0.call_function(test1.py)
>           at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java:167)
>           at org.python.core.PyCode.call(PyCode.java:18)
>           at org.python.core.Py.runCode(Py.java:1386)
>           at org.python.util.PythonInterpreter.execfile(PythonInterpreter.java:296)
>           at org.python.util.jython.run(jython.java:362)
>           at org.python.util.jython.main(jython.java:142) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.io.RawComparator
>           at org.python.core.SyspathJavaLoader.findClass(SyspathJavaLoader.java:131)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>           ... 22 more
>
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/hadoop/io/RawComparator

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

It seems the library is missing from the classpath. By default jython.jar includes only the default python mobules present in the `lib` directory. Any third party module needs to be added in the classpath.

You need to add reference of hbase jar in the library modules as following:

```
jython -Dpython.path=/<location of jar>/hbase.jar test1.py
```

Another option is :

```
java -cp /<location of jar>/hbase.jar;jython.jar org.python.util.jython test1.py
```

Jython Classpath should include HBASE classpath to include all dependencies.

For more details, please refer : 
https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#jython

Comment: I don't have a hbase.jar . I tried importing hbase-common but now I am getting an error "cannot import name TableName"

Comment: You are still missing hbase dependencies. You have to refer the all HBASE jars in your jython classpath.  I have updated the answer with a link, you can refer for details.

Comment: I have done "export HBASE_CLASSPATH=/usr/local/lib/jython/jython.jar" . Anything else I have to do?

Comment: setting HBASE_CLASSPATH will help when you access by `bin/hbase org.python.util.jython` but in order to run from jython cli, you either need to pass `-cp=jar-path`  or set `export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:hbase-jars-location`.

Comment: I have updated my post. I am getting a new error message. I will greatly appreciate any help.